# Constructor implementation with RAII and inheritance

Tags: inheritance, constructor, c++-cli, raii

I'm developing a hardware library for our company's devices, which among other things needs to access a camera and different kinds of illumination. The basic hardware interface is designed like

```
public ref class IHardware abstract {

protected:
    ICamera* camera;
    ILight^ light;
    ...

public:
    IHarware();
    ...
    virtual bool acquireImage() abstract;
    ...
};
```

Here, `ICamera` and `ILight` are interfaces for the corresponding hardware parts.
The DLL that I need to develop contains the above interface as well as a specialization of `IHardware` for our standard devices, let it be called `SHardware`. Spezializations for that device exist for `ICamera` and `ILight` as well, i.e. `SCamera` and `SLight`.
Since I'd like to use RAII, the constructor of `SHardware` looks like

```
SHardware::SHardware : IHardware() {
    ...
    camera = new SCamera();
    camera->Init();
    light = gcnew SLight();
    light->Init();
    ...
}
```

Now, say I'd like to use that SHardware class for further spezialization, e.g. for a class called `NHardware`. I have classes `NCamera` inheiriting from `SCamera` and `NLight` inheiriting from `SLight`. My question is how to implement the constructor of `NHardware`; if it was like

```
NHardware::NHardware() : SHardware() {...}
```

`camera` and `light` are initialized in `SHardware()` already, so that I'd have to `delete` them before creating `NCamera` and `NLight` objects, which seems not correct to me. Of course I could extract camera and illumination initialization in a separate virtual function somehow and override it in the `NHardware` class, but when the `SHardware` constructor is called, isn't also the `SHardware` initialize function used first?
I'm sure this is a quite common problem with rather simple solutions, but right now I just don't get it, so any help is appreciated! Thanks,

Matz

Comment: Why not use a `protected` constructor with a parameter that allows disabling instantiation of the sub-objects? (or directly pass it the new sub-objects)

Comment: Thanks. Sometimes I just don't hit on the easy solution.